# How can I use an array variable to IF statement?

Tags: java

I am developing a simple Taxi Meter Calculator system. I have no idea what to use to implement it. I have written a code but got stuck at IF statement where I had to insert an array variable. I am not sure whether this is the correct way to implement it.

This is the logic.

- The first Km is 50/-.
- Then the next 10Km will be charged 45/- per Km. eg : if 2km were gone
  , charges would be 50/- + 45/- = 95/-, if 3km were gone 140/-.
- The next 10km will be charged 35/- per km
- 25/- per km will be charged no matter how many kms gone after the above 10km exceed.

This is the code I have coded so far

```
private void btn_calActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        int kms1 = 50;
        int kms2 = 45;
        int kms3 = 35;
        int kms4 = 25;
        String[] firstkm={"3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11"};
        if(txt_km.getText().equals("1")){
            lblout.setText(""+kms1);
        }
        if(txt_km.getText().equals("2")){
            lblout.setText(""+(kms1+kms2));
        }if(txt_km.getText().equals(firstkm)){
            int get = Integer.parseInt(txt_km.getText());
            int rate = get+kms2;
            lblout.setText(""+rate);
        }

}
```

if there is any other method to solve this problem please mention it.

Comment: `String[] firstkm={"3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11"};` is a String array with one index. You probably are looking for String[] firstkm={"3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"}; but this would be better served as an `int` array.

Comment: your code's really messed up: String[] firstkm={"3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11"}; will only create one array element with the value:
 "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11"

Comment: Thanks Drew, Is there a way to add like this. eg : {3-11} instead of {1,2,3...}

Comment: @Mittal yes, it means I need to create more arrays?

Comment: @T.BHassim you only need one array. Change the array type to int and remove the quotes inside your {...}. You parsed the input value here `int get = Integer.parseInt(txt_km.getText());`. This is fine, but you should do this before your `if-statement` and use it to compare against an index is your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int fare = 0;
int distance = 0;
if (distance > 21) {
    fare += (distance - 21) * 25;
    distance = 21;
}
if (distance > 11) {
    fare += (distance - 11) * 35;
    distance = 11;
}
if (distance > 1) {
    fare += (distance - 1) * 45;
    distance = 1;
}
if (distance > 0) {
    fare += distance * 50;
}
```

Then refactor by putting the magic numbers into arrays and loop through the arrays (4 times).

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot. But I didn't use arrays and loops. this code worked for me, I added codes this way to my interface button. 
//2nd line `int distance = Integer.parseInt(txt_km.getText());`  
`if (distance > 21) {
    fare += (distance - 21) * 25;
    distance = 21;
    lblout.setText(""+fare);` // added at the end to every IF statement

Comment: Glad it helped.  You could accept it as the answer if you want.

Comment: Oh yes, 1 more question. what is "+=" and what is that "distance = *" in the end of each statement. could you explain

Comment: a +=b means a = a + b;

Comment: Ok let's say a=10; and b=20; so it is a = 10+20; and a=30;

Comment: What's the use of putting 'distance=(value);' at the end of each IF statement

Comment: The distance remaining for the fare calculation must be updated after each rate level.  Try single-stepping with and without and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: Implement this method

```
/**
This method returns the amount a passenger must pay for this kilometer of their trip
*/
public int chargeForKilometer(int kilometerNumberInTrip) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: i don't think the OP would get it that easily :)

Comment: Agree with you guys, I should try and thanks for the hint so I know where to start. thanks Mittal

Answer (score 0):

try

```
String[] firstkm={3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
    if(txt_km.getText().equals(firstkm[1])){
        lblout.setText(""+kms1);
    }
```

....

Comment: Thanks Lord, according to this I have to call each and every index to know the rate.

Answer (score 0):

In case your conditions change and you want to avoid adding if conditions in your code, I wrote a configurable code.

```
public int calculateRate(int kmCount){
    int baseRate = 50;
    int[] stepRate = {45,35};
    int step = 10;
    int fare = 0;
    int threshold = 21;
    int beyondThresholdRate = 25;

    if(kmCount>0){
        fare = baseRate;
        fare += (kmCount - threshold)<0?0:(kmCount - threshold)*beyondThresholdRate;
        kmCount = kmCount - 1;
        for(int i=0;i<=((kmCount/step) + (kmCount%step>0?1:0));i++){
            fare += (kmCount/step)==0?(kmCount%step)*stepRate[i]:step*stepRate[i];
            kmCount -=step;
            if(i==stepRate.length-1) break;
        }
    }
    return fare;
}
```

It is slightly complex, however, flexible.